# How to minimise Thunderbird on startup?

Tags: thunderbird, automation, minimize

Recently, in Cinnamon, Thunderbird resists being minimized by `xdotool`. 
How to minimize it after launch?

Answer (score 0):

To minimize Thunderbird in Cinnamon, use following bash script:

```
until test $THUNDERWIN; do
   sleep 1
   THUNDERWIN=`xdotool search --name ".*- Mozilla Thunderbird$"|head -n 1`
  done
  xdotool windowfocus --sync $THUNDERWIN
  xdotool key Ctrl+Super+m
```

You need to set Ctrl+Super+M as a "Minimize" shortcut in `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Windows`